# Regression Kriging of binomial data in geoRglm R package

Tags: r, logistic-regression, kriging, geostatistics

I am using `binom.krige()` function of the R package **geoRglm** for determining the spatial predictions of a binary (0, 1) response variable with several continuous as well as discrete covariates.

Using `glm()` with binomial logit link function I found that the response variable is showing significant dependency on several covariates.

I included the trend into `binom.krige()` using `krige.glm.control()` where I  specified the two trend models as

```
> trend.d=trend.spatial(~ rivers + roads + annual_pre + annual_tem + elevation_ + host_densi + lulc + moist_dq + moist_in + moist_wq, data_points)

> trend.l=trend.spatial(~ rivers1 + roads + annual_pre + annual_tem + elevation_ + host_densi + lulc + moist_dq + moist_in + moist_wq, pred_grid)
```

The question, which is confusing me, is when `trend.d` and `trend.l` go into `krige.glm.control()` and eventually into `binom.krige()`, does it actually fit a **glm** with **binomial logit** or just linear model (because the above equations seem to be a linear model)?

Comment: Which dataset are you using? It will be easier for me to reproduce the error if you give me complete information.